# What is a musical pattern and how do you use it in style?

Tags: theory, technique, composition, rhythm, styles

In music theory what is a **music pattern** as it relates to *style*?  Here is a quote I got from this website to help one get my question about style... and the use of "musical pattern. " "Style refers to characteristic features of how music (of a certain era, or within some particular genre) is played or expected to sound, i.e. its actual musical content - the set of expected "musical patterns", mannerisms, expressive devices it conventionally makes use of" comment made under "In music what's the difference between genre and style."

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @mkorman no it's not

Comment: You need to give more context. Where did you see such a reference to a "pattern" and "style" ... in a book, web page, video...?

Comment: @piiperi Reinstate Monica I changed my question, hopes this helps.

Answer (score 6):

A pattern is *anything* whose form repeats.

It's hard to talk about nearly *anthing* in music without a pattern being involved. *Meter* itself is a pattern, so if you are dealing with metered music - which is a lot of music - it's patterned.

A more obvious example is a *harmonic pattern*. In pop music the chords `I V vi IV` is a common pattern repeated over and over to accompany a song.

A lot of style elements come down to rhythmic/harmonic patterns. In country music a common pattern is the bass playing chord roots and fifths in quarter notes in common time. Descriptions of accompaniment patterns like that are important for defining a style. But patterns can involve other musical elements. It all depends on the particular style of music.

Answer (score 1):

First off let me say that a music pattern can be any number of things when applied generally to music, but since you stated " as it relates to style", I will point out something such as a rhythm which is commonly used in a particular genre of music such as Reggae, or maybe a common number of bars that may be used such as the twelve bar Blues. Some might say a particular time signature might be a music pattern such as 3/4 is commonly called a waltz. In any event, a pattern in music can be defined as a repetitious characteristic that different styles of music might employ.

Answer (score 0):

A **musical pattern** is a type of pattern seen in the sheet music. For example, one type of a musical pattern is sequence. **Sequence** is when you play a motive, then you play it a whole step or a half step above.

Here is an example of sequence:
[image]

Another type of a musical pattern is **imitation**: where the treble clef or the bass clef play a phrase and the other clef imitates it:

[image]

Another type of pattern is **ostinato**. Ostinato is a repeated phrase or pattern:
[image]

Another type, similar to the last is **pedal point**. Where a note (usual in the bass) is continually repeated or held:

[image]

I hope that helped! Let me know if have any questions.